# How can I assign users to specific pages in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, settings

We have a site that has locations.

Example:

1. mysite.com/atlanta
2. mysite.com/boston
3. mysite.com/denver

Each user can only edit their respective location/page(s). We want to grant them access only to their page set in google analytics....is this possible?

Example: user A  = /atlanta/* and user B = /boston/*

We basically want to silo off where they only see their location pages and no one else's data.

Any assistance would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create 3 views and provide edit permissions only to a user at the view level.

The permissions are inherited, so if you give the edit permissions at the property level, the user will automatically have the same permissions at the view level (for all the views of the property).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So each location would be a view, and then assign that user to the view.